# When is a destructor called with multiple function calls and with QTimer?

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I have a class that completes an action in its destructor.
It is called in a separate class' function that calls another function and so on.

```
void method3()
{
    //action gets done
}

void method2()
{
    //action gets done
    method3();
}

void method1()
{
    obj o;
    //action gets done
    QTimer::singleShot( 1000, this, SLOT( method2() ) );
}
```

Without using `QTimer::singleShot` and just calling `method2()` the destructor is called after `method3()` has finished.

When is obj's destructor called when using `QTimer::singleShot` to call `method2()`?
Is there anyway to use `QTimer::singleShot` and have the destructor called normally at the end of `method3()`?

Comment: Not quite right: The destructor is called when method1 is finished, in both cases. When you use an asynchronous mechanism such as QTimer (disclaimer I know nothing about QT but speaking from knowledge of basic c++ principles) then the lifetimes of local stack based objects end when the scope they are created in ends. If you wish to prolong the lifetime of the object it first needs to be heap based (ignoring globals). Your best option is to use a shared pointer and pass it to method2 and then as a raw pointer or reference to method3, as it is called synchronously.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `o` object of type `obj` has **automatic [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)** inside the scope of `method1`, it will be destroyed when the mentioned scope ends, i.e. `method1` finishes.

In first case when you called `method2` without [`QTimer::singleShot`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot), you just performed a normal function call which will return to `method1`. So, `method1` will be finished when `method2` returns.

In second case you created an event by calling `QTimer::singleShot` which will return immediately after the event is created, therefore `method1` will be finished before the call of `method2` occurs.

Too prolong the lifetime of `o` object, you have to create it with **dynamic storage duration**, then destroy it when `method3` finishes. This can be done by [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) and [`delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) operators but I suggest using of [`QSharedPointer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html) or other smart pointers.

Here is my solution to your issue:

```
#include <QSharedPointer>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QObject>

class obj {
public:
    obj() { qDebug() << "Instance of 'obj' is created."; }
    ~obj() { qDebug() << "Instance of 'obj' is destroyed."; }
};

class Foo : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void method3() {
        qDebug() << "Foo::method3 called.";
        m_obj.reset(); // destroys the previously created 'obj' instance
    }
    void method2() {
        qDebug() << "Foo::method2 called.";
        method3();
    }
    void method1() {
        m_obj.reset(new obj); // creates a new 'obj' instance
        qDebug() << "Foo::method1 called.";
        QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(method2()));
    }
private:
    QSharedPointer<obj> m_obj;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`o` has [automatic storage class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), which means it is deallocated at the end of enclosing block:

```
void method1()
{
    obj o;
    //action gets done
    QTimer::singleShot( 1000, this, SLOT( method2() ) );
} // o ceases to exist here
```

`method2` is scheduled to be run in some point in future, notably after `method1` has returned, so automatic variables declared in `method1` are not available anymore.

If you need `o` to persist you can either

- declare `o` as class member, as `method1` seems to be member function of some class
- allocate it with `new` or, better, use smart pointers (probably `std::unique_ptr` would be the best fit here) and deallocate it manually when no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can create `o` only when the timer actually activates. You can use a lambda function for that:

```
void method1()
{
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, [this]
    {
        obj o;
        // Do your stuff here.
        method2();
    });
}
```

Here, `o` is only created when the timer actually activates (which executes the lambda,) not when `method1()` is called.

If this is not suitable for your use-case and you really need to create the object when `method1()` is called and not when the timer activates, you can use a shared pointer to prevent your object from being destroyed before the timer fires:

```
#include <memory>
// ...

void method1()
{
    auto o_ptr = std::make_shared<obj>(/* ctor arguments here */);
    // Do your stuff here.

    QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, [o_ptr, this]{ method2(); });
}
```

Since we're capturing `o_ptr` in the lambda, the object is not going to be destroyed. It will only be destroyed after the lambda has finished. `shared_ptr` guarantees that the object it holds will not be destroyed if anyone is still holding a reference to the `shared_ptr`. In this case, the lambda is holding a reference which keeps the object alive. Once the lambda finishes executing, the reference is released and the object is destroyed.